# Min-width set to min-content in flex elements not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that can hold an indefinite number of elements.

Every element is divided in 3 parts. The first and third parts should fit their content and should never be shrunk or hidden, the middle part it holds a text that can be shrunk until a min of 10 characters.

I need to show as much information as possible for every element. if all elements fit in the container the text should be shown entirely, if they don't fit, the elements should start shrinking the text allowing to show as many elements as possible, once is not possible to shrink the text because it reached its minimum then the latest elements (more to the right) should overflow the parent and the be hidden.
I'm using flexbox like follows.

```html
    <div class="tabs-container">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab-element-1">
          ele1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-2">
          Text
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-3">
          tab element 3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab-element-1">
          ele1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-2">
          Some Very Very Very Long Text
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-3">
          123456789 123456789 123456789
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab-element-1">
          ele1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-2">
          Really Very Very Very Very long long text even longer
        </div>
        <div class="tab-element-3">
          tab element 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  min-width: 12rem;
/*   min-width: min-content; */
}

.tab-element-1 {
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: none;
}

.tab-element-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 10ch;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.tab-element-3 {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: none;
}
```

I think the problem is with the min-width set to a fixed value in the elements, but I cannot find the proper value to set, I tried with min-content but is not working.
For every element, the min-width should be equal to:
the size of the left part content + min width of middle part's content (10ch) + the size of the right part content.
But I don't know how to accomplished this with css.

codepen here: https://codepen.io/alejandro-palmer/pen/eYvZRrJ

In the given example the second element starts shrinking and its third part overflows and is hidden, even when the text of the third element can be shrunk even more.
[image]

Comment: Consider simplifying your question and code sample. You have six flex containers in play. Perhaps remove all code unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin example simplified removing unrelated code

Comment: Let me understand, you don't want to wrap line; if the line gets bigger, you want to hide part of it. Correct?

Comment: @ArnonDePaula yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you can take out a layer of HTML, this is much more feasible than nesting flexboxes:

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab-element-1">
      ele1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-2">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-3">
      tab element 3
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-element-1">
      ele1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-2">
      Some Very Very Very Long Text
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-3">
      123456789 123456789 123456789  
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-element-1">
      ele1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-2">
      Really Very Very Very Very long long text even longer
    </div>
    <div class="tab-element-3">
      tab element 3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.tab-element-1 {
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.tab-element-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 0 10ch;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.tab-element-3 {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.tab-element-3:not(:last-child) {margin-right:10px;}
```

If you can't take out a layer, use this CSS instead:

```
.tabs-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.tab-element-1 {
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.tab-element-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 0 10ch;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.tab-element-3 {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.tab-element-3:not(:last-child) {margin-right:10px;}
```

Comment: Kate, thanks for your answer, but I cannot remove a layer of HTML. Every element is a React component from a 3rd party library that is wrapping my content, I can style the wrapping components of the 3rd party library but I cannot remove layers.

Comment: It just occurred to me that although nested flexboxes don't quite work, a grid and a flexbox do. Please see my amended answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @PALMERALE, I'd love to know if this is working for you! Please could you give me a quick update?

Comment: sorry I didn't reply before and thanks for your time. Your latest solution is arranging the elements(tabs) in different rows, I need them all in the same row, I tried to play a bit with the grid but I'm not that familiar with it. At the moments because time constraints I'm calculating the min-width with JS :(